# Problem with USB-C Monitor Blinking in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, multiple-monitors, display

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 fresh install in my hp laptop.

I have an usb-c hp monitor connected to it and another monitor connected with an HDMI cable.

Both monitors "seems" to work, but the *usb-c one starts blinking and going to black every few seconds from time to time*.

Everything was working perfectly last week when I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed ( same hardware, same cables, same connections).

I have try everything I have been able to think of .. but with no success ..

**Any help would be more than welcomed.**

---

Hint: With Ubuntu 16.04 my desktop manager was **i3**, now I am using **Gnome** ... not sure if this could make any difference, but with i3 I had to use arandr to tell the system to use the monitor every time I start the computer while Gnome seems to "automagically" detect the display, so maybe there is some process checking for new displays that could be screwing up ? ( or maybe I am seeing ghosts where there is nothing ... )